# grabbing apex:commandButton using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I am trying to grab a visual force element using jQuery and having some trouble.

In my source my save button looks like this:

```
<apex:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
```

And in my document.ready I have this statement:

```
alert('button value ' + $("[id$=saveButton]").value);
```

But all I get when I load the page is:

> 'button value undefined'.

Eventually I want to disable the button programmatically from within a JavaScript function, but I don't think I am even able to grab the element.

The chrome inspector says my element looks like this:

```
<input id="j_id0:frm:searchBlock:saveButton" type="submit" name="j_id0:frm:searchBlock:saveButton" value="Save" onclick="saveButtonClicked();" class="btn" disabled="disabled">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wish I knew why the proposed solution (below) works and the one I tried fails (for certain buttons).

Comment: The issue is you are using .value  ---- use .val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert('button value ' + $("#j_id0\\:frm\\:searchBlock\\:saveButton").val());
```

To disable:

```
$("#j_id0\\:frm\\:searchBlock\\:saveButton").attr("disabled", "");
```

Comment: That is so wierd! Why does $("[id$= work for one of my buttons but not for others? Why does your solution work?

Comment: You have to use the full id, including escaping the colons: `j_id0\\:frm\\:searchBlock\\:saveButton`

Comment: Micah, your selector should work fine. The problem is with .value --- this is not a property of a jQuery object. You have to use val(), as Jeremy does. You do NOT have to use the full Id --- your id$= method works fine.

Comment: zachelrath is correct. However, I usually prefer to use the full Id to avoid cases where the $= selector could match multiple elements.

Comment: I tend to use a unique class name for each button, just to keep the jQuery selectors clean and simple!

Answer (score 2):

When using jQuery, use `$("selector").val();` not `$("selector").value;`. `$("selector").value;` will be undefined.

In your case, use: `$("[id$=saveButton]").val();`.

To **disable**:

```
$("[id$=saveButton]")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled")
    .removeClass("btn")
    .addClass("btnDisabled");
```

To **re-enable**:

```
$("[id$=saveButton]")
    .removeAttr("disabled")
    .removeClass("btnDisabled")
    .addClass("btn");
```

Comment: Still trying to decide whether or not to use this approach or Zachelrath's below. In anycase it is correct, and I have verified it works!

Answer (score 1):

Micah, your basic issue is that you're using .value with a jQuery object --- this is returning undefined because .value is not a property of jQuery objects. Use .val().

Your "ends-with" selector method works fine, and is by far the easiest way of consistently retrieving Visualforce elements by Id --- so don't change anything here.

On a side note, if you're trying to manipulate this button from within JavaScript, I'd suggest not using a CommandButton. Anything you can achieve with a CommandButton you can achieve with a regular input button, like so, and then you don't have to worry about (1) messing with standard Visualforce elements, which are often wrapped in several layers of DIVs (2) Rerendering issues. For instance, if you want to do some JavaScript prior to calling an Apex action (whether standard or custom), and still have your "command button" show up in the pageBlockButtons, do this:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="mySaveButton" 
        onclick="saveButtonClicked();" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

This will render a button that looks EXACTLY like a CommandButton, plus you can easily access/disable it in jQuery:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// To disable the button programmatically
// (in jQuery 1.7+) on page load:
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#mySaveButton').prop('disabled',true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about whether or not to just use regular input  buttons. It does seem simpler, but I'm afraid I won't be able to call the same apex controller methods from a non-Command button (esp since JavaScript remoting seems to require functions are static) ... but I'm not sure if that is right. In any case, thanks for the insight here! Got a lot to learn about VF.